# Fabric: executing inline Python on target host?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fabric

This Fabric command works just fine for `fab local grab_from_s3:bucket=...`:

```
def grab_from_s3(bucket, path, localfile):
    s3_connection = S3Connection()
    s3_bucket = s3_connection.get_bucket(bucket)
    s3_key = Key(s3_bucket)
    s3_key.key = path
    s3_key.get_contents_to_filename(localfile)
```

Of course, if I feed it a remote target host, it downloads to the local host and not the remote. (i.e. `fab staging grab_from_s3:bucket=...`).

I'm hoping one of these possibilities exists:

1. That task can be automatically run on the remote box with a minimum of coding fuss, or
2. I can programmatically detect that the target host isn't local, and specify a fabric command line for the remote host.

I'd vastly prefer #1, but it's not clear if that's even possible.  What's not clear about #2 is whether there are existing Fabric facilities that makes this easy (i.e. detecting the local/remote hosts and the fact that they're different).

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Fabric doesn't support running arbitrary python code on a remote host. Fabric mostly runs by invoking shell commands over SSH (for remote machines). The remote machine doesn't even need python installed for Fabric to work.

The [execnet](http://codespeak.net/execnet/) project allows you to run python code over the network like you're imagining, you can run the same code without modifications locally and remotely.

The simplest solution might be to have the same fabric code deployed to both the local host and the remote host, then have the local task run the S3 download task remotely (via a shell command).

One problem you will run into (both with execnet and running the fab task on the remote machine) is that you'll need boto installed on the remote machine. Not sure if you have that setup already.

Another option would be to run a command line tool like [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) or the [official AWS command line client](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) via fabric on the remote host.

Answer (score 2):

Use Fabric on your local host to run Fabric on the remote host, which will allow you to execute Python commands on the remote host. Since Fabric configurations can be very complex, the following is a snippet that will not necessarily work in your environment without modification. For example, the command to run Fabric may be different on various platforms.

Define a function in your fabfile to execute the desired Python code:

```
def local_grab_from_s3():
    bucket = "my_bucket"
    path = "my_path"
    localfile = "local_filename"

    s3_connection = S3Connection()
    s3_bucket = s3_connection.get_bucket(bucket)
    s3_key = Key(s3_bucket)
    s3_key.key = path
    s3_key.get_contents_to_filename(localfile)
```

Define another function call the first function on the remote host:

```
def grab_from_s3():
    cmd("fab local_grab_from_s3")
```

On the command line of the local host, run `fab -H remote_host grab_from_s3`